# I get incorrect numbers while dividing two columns

Tags: powerbi

With this code and the attached photo why I get incorrect numebrs for priceforunit last column?!! for example the last column for the first row should be 117556.23/2829 = 41.55

priceofeachunit = DIVIDE(data_sales_20k[20KG_Bag_RevenueEUR],data_sales_20k[20KG_Bag_UnitsSold])

[image]

Comment: Usually these errors are when you are using more than one table with missing/improper relationships. Your screen shot needs to be a little wider. What's a column and what's a measure? Which table is DEPARTURETIMEUTC on? If a different table, what is relationship to data_sales_20k?

Comment: Also you need to check if the datatype of both of these columns are the same, along the data relationship modelling because that might also be a cause